# Checkbox not saving into database

Tags: mysql, vb.net, checkbox

I have my checkbox1 and when i checked it and save it to the database it should save "administrator" to my type column. But the problem is when i save it nothing happens and it shows no error in my if statement. but when i try my elseif and else statement it is saving perfectly into my database. i already converted my checkbox to a string.

```
 If ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "" And CheckBox1.Checked Then
            Query = "insert into database.logininfo (Username,Password,College,type) Values ('" & TextBox1username.Text & "','" & TextBox1pass.Text & "', '" & ComboBox1.SelectedItem & "', '" & type & "')"
            MessageBox.Show("Data Saved")

ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a college")

 Else : Query = "insert into database.logininfo (Username,Password,College,Type) Values ('" & TextBox1username.Text & "','" & TextBox1pass.Text & "', '" & ComboBox1.SelectedItem & "')"
            MessageBox.Show("Data Saved")
```

Comment: What is `type`?  Is it supposed to the checkbox value?  What type is it?  The checkbox would seem to infer it is a Boolean, but you are converting to string?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "I already converted my checkbox to a string".  You should be using ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() to obtain the text value.  Alternatively you can use SelectedText or SelectedValue depending upon what property you need.